# Idiom for giving someone what they want

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for giving someone what they want, not in a capitulation sense but as agreement that the best course of action is to just deliver 100% of what is being requested?

E.g., "After considering the options, we figured that the best way forward was [to meet the letter of their request/let them find what they're looking for]." Like if "let them eat cake" was less sardonic and more literal, or "let them feast" if you actually thought feasting would be best for everyone involved.

Comment: The best way forward is to concede to their request?

Comment: if you give someone what they want, doesn't that mean **accept** whatever they requested?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to do something that will `tick all their boxes`.  This is quite a modern usage, probably originating from form-filling, and when people have long lists of requirements, and when a given outcome satisfies all their separate requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a very tricky one.

So, I am assuming that you want to tell that the impact is good/positive if you give them what they want. right? If so, how about using the idiom, "**butter someone up**"? You can replace someone with them here.

The meaning is when you praise someone's good, they do as per your expectation. Hope this one helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of *accommodating*:

**accommodating
: willing to please : HELPFUL, OBLIGING**

[(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodating)

> Recent Examples on the Web:
>
> *Eventually, Brussels expects Britain, whether or not still led by Mr
>   Johnson, to have to come back to the negotiating table with a more
>   **accommodating** approach.*
>
> [...]

Answer (score 1):

**satisfy**

"After considering the options, we figured that the best way forward was to satisfy them."

> **satisfy**  VERB
>   1 Meet the expectations, needs, or desires of (someone)
>   1.1 Fulfil (a desire or need)
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/satisfy)

Answer (score 0):

There are many idioms - commonality of use is probably industry specific. You might say to your team:

"We're going to ***deliver*** on this."

"We need to ***step-up*** here."

"***Take good care*** of this client." (US)